# how to detect the incoming message from sim800 GSM module

Tags: gsm

I am designing an motorcycle security system and I need to receive the message  from the user.Hence i need to detect the incoming message and read the number and data from the message

Comment: How does your question differ from http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/2899/6628 ?

Comment: i am not using gsm shield i am using sim800

Comment: So you are looking for the specific codes or a library for receving SMSs on the SIM800?  Wiring? Code for parsing the messages?

Comment: yea, i need to first identify the incoming  message if it is received i need to the parse the phone number and content of the message